# wordpress: Can I avoid "<" and ">" being converted to "&lt:" and "&gt;" inside href tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to add a link on my wordpress website to take the user to the wordpress default "forgot password" page. Here is the wordpress documentation page I am working off of:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_lostpassword_url

I am adding the link as text in the wordpress text editor as I don't have direct access to the source files. I am using the example html from the documentation page:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url(); ?>" title="Lost Password">Lost Password</a>
```

However, when I save the page, the "greater than" and "less than" brackets are converted to their respective html encoding so on the site instead of displaying the url as the href value, the string literal `"<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url(); ?>"` is displayed.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: WP's probably not aware that you're trying to embed PHP in some text, so it's properly encoding the `<>` into character entities.

Comment: Do you not have access to the files through Appearance > Editor?

Comment: Well, yes, thank you for paraphrasing the issue I am describing. The question remains if there is a way to avoid that. Or in other words, is there a way to make wordpress aware that I am trying to embed php code?

Comment: @DannyHearnah I am not sure. There are 2 issues I am having with Appearance > Editor. The first one is that I am not able to save the files I am editing. I am not sure if I am missing some privileges but it's not working. Secondly, I don't even know in which file I would find the html chunk I am trying to modify. I am not seeing the file that would correspond to the page on which I am trying to put that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress will not parse PHP code. There are plugins that can do it if you desire, but they are less than optimal. Instead, try something like this...

In your functions.php file:

```
add_shortcode('lostpassword_url', 'my_lostpassword_url');

function my_lostpassword_url($atts){
    return wp_lostpassword_url();
}
```

In the page with your form:

```
<a href="[lostpassword_url]" title="Lost Password">Lost Password</a>
```

This will tell WordPress to parse the content of your page/post and replace the [lostpassword_url] with the function call.

Comment: Thanks. I don't currently have access to functions.php but when I do I will try this.

Answer (score 3):

It's not beautiful, it's not fancy, I have no proud of that, but it just work:

```
function callback($buffer) {
    $buffer = str_replace('&amp;','&',$buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace('&gt;','>',$buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace('&quot;','"',$buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace('&lt;','<',$buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
function buffer_start() { ob_start("callback"); }
function buffer_end() { ob_end_flush(); }
add_action('wp_head', 'buffer_start');
add_action('wp_footer', 'buffer_end');
```

That's the only solution worked when displaying PHP code on my posts.